# DB2 retrieving multiple occurrences of a xml element

Tags: sql, xml, db2, xmltable

I am new to querying xml.

I have a table NOTIFICATIONS that contains a xml string in the attribute CONTENT.
The content of the attribute looks like this (formated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<interuptionLimitation xmlns="http://example.com/schema">
    <person>1000000</person>
    <date>2020-07-20</date>
    <reason>Contact</reason>
    <debtId>1</debtId>
    <debtId>2</debtId>
</interuptionLimitation>
```

debId can occur multiple times

In DB2 I would like the output as:

```
person  date       reason debtId
1000000 2020-07-20 Contact 1
1000000 2020-07-20 Contact 2
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT X.*
FROM NOTIFICATIONS n
 , XMLTABLE ('$I/interuptionLimitation ' PASSING XMLPARSE(document n.CONTENT) as "I"
  COLUMN
  "person" bigint PATH 'person',
  "date"  CHAR(10) PATH 'date',
  "reason" VARCHAR(200) PATH 'reason',
  "debtId" bigint  PATH '@debtId') AS X
```

Unfortunately this gives no output.

Can someone help me with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH NOTIFICATIONS (CONTENT) AS 
(
VALUES '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<interuptionLimitation xmlns="http://example.com/schema">
    <person>1000000</person>
    <date>2020-07-20</date>
    <reason>Contact</reason>
    <debtId>1</debtId>
    <debtId>2</debtId>
</interuptionLimitation>'
)
*/
SELECT X.*
FROM NOTIFICATIONS n
, XMLTABLE 
(
XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://example.com/schema'),
'$I/interuptionLimitation/debtId' PASSING XMLPARSE(document n.CONTENT) as "I"
  COLUMNS
  "person" bigint       PATH '../person',
  "date"   CHAR(10)     PATH '../date',
  "reason" VARCHAR(200) PATH '../reason',
  "debtId" bigint       PATH '.'
) AS X;
```